# Angular2 load only specified Component

Tags: angular

First of all. I'm newbie in Angular2.
I have 4 selectors in one of my content file:

```
<ng-comp1></ng-comp1>
<ng-comp2></ng-comp2>
<ng-comp3></ng-comp3>
<ng-comp4></ng-comp4>
```

In my component.ts file, there are the Components declarations, like the first:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'ng-comp1',
   template: '...'
})
export class AppComponent1 {}
```

There is another content file, which contains only the `<ng-comp1></ng-comp1>` and `<ng-comp2></ng-comp2>` directive.
It gives me an error, that:

> The selector "ng-comp3" did not match any elements. and The selector
>   "ng-comp4" did not match any elements.

How can I resolve this? Or could I check the availability of selectors before Component creating?

Thanks,
 Imre

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? Angular (since version 2) uses TypeScript (but can also be written in pure JavaScript)

Comment: I have a site in asp.net C# webform and I have started to change the webform controls to Angular2 Materials.
www.recognitiongame.com

Comment: Thanks yurzui!

I have read that and it works! ;-)